# Migrate a 32-bit app installed on x64 to x86

Tags: windows, x86, migration, 64-bit

A little backwards from the usual.  I have a 32-bit application in a vm running 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate.  This program doesn't function as well as it would in a 32-bit OS due to its age and 32-bit device driver.  To that end I have set up a Windows 7 x86 Pro vm.  Now the problem is I want to migrate this application and I'd rather not have to re-install it and set it all up again.  Is this possible?

Comment: find ALL of the app's files, ALL of the app's registry keys, and copy them to the new vm. Beyond that, the question is offtopi for this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, **No** (Not atleast in a reliable and painless way).

As you mentioned, it is a legacy application that has device drivers involved. That means that there needs to some mechanism to install the drivers which is normally done by the installs. Also it will most probably involve DCOM or Vb which needs registration using regsvr32. Also if you feel the pain of setting it up again, then that means that this application has lots of associated prerequisites to be installed and settings scattered around in registry entries, .xml and .ini files.

Unfortunately Microsoft does not support upgrade from x86 to x64 and vice-versa.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't figure it would be easy or even probable but I had to ask first.  Thanks!